# convert all date data type column to YYYY-MM-DD format dynamically when col having date format in dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am attempting to convert dynamically all date columns to YYYY-MM-DD format using dataframe that come from read_csv. columns are below.

```
empno   ename   sal deptno  period_from hiredate    report_date end_date
```

using re , searching if column having "period or date" chars then converting to YYYY-MM-DD format but the problem is some of the columns dont have "period or date" which are actually date columns(example "from" col).

```
df_columns = [col for col in df.columns if re.search("period|date"),col)]
df(df_columns] = df[df_columns].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Now i want create a method/function to identify all date datatype columns in dataframe then convert to YYYY-MM-DD format/user expected format.

[image]

Comment: please provide your datasets as **text**, not images

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
for col in df.filter(regex='period|date'):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

Difficult to give you a much better answer and the output without a example dataset as text, please update your question for more details.

If you only have those formats `01-01-2021`/`17-Jun-2021`/`18/06/2021`/`31122021`, the following should handle all of them. Only the latter case requires to specify the format. If you have something more complex, you'll need to do some parsing.

```
for col in df.filter(regex='period|date'):
    try:
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
    except TypeError:
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%d%m%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @mozway. actually there is another column("From" ) having date format. I want check dynamically if column data type is date then convert YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: I got solution. Thanks for your time and help.